# Is there a data structure for storing 2D points of natural numbers, which allows checking for existence in O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I want a data structure which can store a list of n 2D points (x,y) of natural numbers, and then allows to check if a given point exists in the original list of points in O(1) complexity time, and this time complexity should be **deterministic** (meaning a Hash table is not an option). The creation of this data structure should also be efficient as possible. I can't use a data structure which requires some initialization in time complexity which is worse then O(n * sqrt(n)).

Is a data structure like that exists?

Comment: Array lookup by index is `O(1)`, so set up a logical array with `true` at existing points, `false` elsewhere.  I think this satisfies your second requirement for the complexity of initialisation too.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark unfortunatelly, he needs a 2D array with size of `n*n`

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. You can also upvote answers now so they are positioned higher and the author is awarded additional reputation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Comment: @MattTimmermans that's a nice approach, but it won't help with the constraint of the initialisation time of the data structure. You could only create `O(nsqrt(n))` buckets which would lead to the access time of `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: @xenteros O(n * sqrt(n)) is plenty of time for initialization.  n is the number of points

Comment: @MattTimmermans I have a simpler explanation. `identity` is the simplest perfect hash function for this problem :) In case you want a function which is `N^2 -> N`, as we work with integers, we can say, that `(X,Y) -> X + Y<<32` but this is not the case. The problem is that fast initialization of an array, as only array might have that `O(1)` lookup time complexity

Comment: @xenteros Yes, I know, but I thought the OP might like a solution that doesn't require an exabyte of RAM, even if it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: @MattTimmermans don't you think, that this is just an university exercise for algorithms and data structures? That's how I see it. If it was a real problem, there would be technology tag attached. I would also go for a regular HashTable and agree with `O(nn)` initialization time complexity

Comment: What is `n` here? Is this a matrix of size `n x n`? Or is `n` the total capacity (i.e. `width * height`? Or is `n` perhaps the number of points in the original list? With the ambiguity in what `n` you're talking about, this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @JimMischel I assumed the range of positive integers

Comment: @xenteros thanks for your answer! n is the number of points given in the original list. And it is indeed a question from my university

Comment: Anyway, my answer still works

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does exist.

First of all, let's think about the first candidate for the `O(1)` contains operation. The first natural candidate is a 2D array. The problem is the other constraint which says that the initialization time complexity must be `O(n*sqrt(n))`.

What if we don't initialize values? We might be satisfied with the random rubbish that is already in these memory cells and mark a point as in the array by setting `arr[x][y]` to 1 or any other value.

This might unfortunately lead to a false positive with a very small probability, but we can't initialize `arr` to zeros, as it would take `O(n^2)`.

Fortunately, an algorithm for constant array initialization exists. I'll describe it here later on, but for now, you can read about it [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/23/initializing-an-array-in-constant-time/)

## Algorithm description

Let us have an array `point_filter` of size `MAX_INT x MAX_INT` and two arrays of that size too. Let's call them `FROM` and `TO`. We'll also need an indicator `TOP` initialized to 0.

```
point_filter: array MAX_INT x MAX_INT
FROM:         array MAX_INT x MAX_INT
TO:           array MAX_INT x MAX_INT
TOP:          0
```

and we assume, that all values in arrays are unsigned ints.

We'll say, that the element i of `point_filter` has been visited already if and only if `FROM[i] < TOP and TO[FROM[i]] = i`

If the above condition is met, the value of `point_filter[i]` is returned, initial value (let's say 0) otherwise.

To set `point_filter` for the first time do:

```
FROM[i] = TOP
TO[TOP] = i
point_filter[i] = 1 //visited, point in filter
TOP++
```

this way, the initialization of the `point_filter` takes `O(1)`. To say, that point `i` is in the collection, just follow the above steps, and to check if the point was inserted before, just check if `FROM[i] < TOP and TO[FROM[i]] = i`.

Now you need to adjust the algorithm for a 2D array which is quite simple. Just replace `[i]` with `[i][j]` and the algorithm will still work.

Comment: as far as I understand, the array size of your solution is not `n*n` but `(max(x)-min(x)) * (max(y) - min(y))`. what will happen if  the 2D point array is `[(1,2), (3000000, 40000000)]` ?

Comment: A small question - n specifies the number of points given in the original list. According to your solution, if I understand correctly, the arrays we should allocate are of size MAX_X * MAX_Y, which can be quite large (all I now is that for every point, x and y are natural numbers, but not bounded). Did I understand correctly? If so, then this solution unfortunatly may not fit for me.

Answer (score -2):

I think in this case you have to choose either you want 100% accuracy in result or 100% guarantee on O(1). As you have stated you want absolute guarantee on O(1) solution, what you can have is an algorithm with very close to 100% accuracy. The data structure goes like this:

```
class ConstantLookup:
    class Hashers:
        def __init__(self, seed, len):
            self.seed = seed
            self.len = len
        def hash(self, x, y):
            ... perform your hash function in respect to seed here ...
            return hash_result % len
    def __init__(self, n_hashers, len):
             self.hashers = [Hashers(random.randint(0,1000, len) for i in range(n_hashers)]
             self.lists = [[False] * len for i in range(n_hashers)]

    def insert(self, x, y):
             for i, h in enumerate(self.hashers):
                 hash = h.hash(x, y)
                 self.list[i][hash] = True
    def contains(self, x, y):
             for i, h in enumerate(self.hashers):
                 hash = h.hash(x, y)
                 if not self.list[i][hash]:
                     return False
             return True
```

With large enough *len* and *n_hashers*, you will get close to 100% accuracy while the running complexity for insertion is O(len * n_hashers * n) and the lookup complexity is O(len * n_hashers) which can be considered constant.

Assuming the hashers are well designed, the chance of giving false positive is *(n/len) ^ n_hashers*

The obvious drawbacks in this method is deletion will not be allowed.

Comment: Please have a look at my solution. It meets all constraints.

Comment: Your solution requires a minimum O(m^2) space complexity which may be impractical in real world situation. Also, even your solution can be improved by having multiple point_filter with true values set to different magic numbers. You should not down vote an answer offering a different angle from yours just because it's a competing answer.

Comment: The practicality of this solution is out of scope of this question. In terms of practicality, the hash table would be best.

Comment: `you have to choose either you want 100% accuracy in result or 100% guarantee on O(1).` is not true

Comment: Ok. I think I have misread your algorithm. Thanks for pointing out